# Socket.io and Redis pub/sub

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I want to use socket.io, but I'll be running multiple instances of my app, so that's where things get interesting.

- I need to run multiple instances on different ports. No problem here.
- I decided not to use Node's own cluster, I'll use Nginx for load balancing (that's why I create multiple instances of the app). Nginx supports websockets, so this one is also sorted out.
- Given that there'll be multiple instances, not all of them can't talk to each other directly (user A connects to instance X, if user B is connected to instance Y, they can't communicate since servers are independent from each other), so I need to use Redis' pub/sub mechanism as a wrapper in order to mimick socketio's emit & broadcast functionality. This way even if I have multiple instances of an app or run it on different servers, everybody will be able to talk to each other as long as they're connected to the same Redis server. To achieve this, I'll need to use socket.io-redis and socket.io-emitter modules.

Have I got that right, is there something wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds about right probably except are you sure you need multiple instances of your Node app on different ports?  Because you might be able to handle more load than you would assume with one server and there are ways to separate out different communications channels with socket.io.

Comment: I want to utilize all CPU's, it seems that there are two ways to achieve it, using cluster module (native solution) or creating multiple instances (equals to number of cores), using Redis for pub/sub for socket communication (since they can't talk to each other directly if they aren't on the same server) and letting Nginx handle load balancing between these instances. It also should work for multiple servers that run multiple instances. Is that correct?

Comment: I think what you are saying will work, just thought you might want to double-check if you actually were CPU bound that way.  Of course it is nice to have a scalable solution if you run into CPU/IO issues down the road with just one process, but that is no guarantee you will run into that bottleneck.

Comment: I probably won't run into that bottleneck anytime soon (maybe never), but I want to have a scalable solution that utilizes as many as resources it can. Thanks!

Comment: @salep, I am using Redis 3  publish and subscribe with a custom C++11 output plugin which buffers avionics messages on a sorted STL std::list which is flushed when it reaches a length of 5000 and disconnects when the redis.conf hard and soft REDIS client output buffer iimits are reached.How could I use your idea of   creating multiple instances (equals to number of cores, using Redis for pub/sub for socket communication to handle the load of 0.4 million bytes per second? Thank you.